# как по известной URL ссылке получить csv файл и как с ним работать?

Tags: java, csv

задача - по известной ссылке получить указанный csv-файл(таблица) и вытащить из него 10 элементов с наибольшим показателем в одном из столбцов.

Как это сделать? Где можно посмотреть пример выполнения этого кода? так же интересует пример обработки такой таблицы - поиск чего бы то ни было в ней.

Comment: "Java download url" и "Java CSV" уже погуглили перед тем, как задавать вопросы?

Comment: нашел много на английском, но с техническим английским возникли сложности - понять до уровня "ок, я могу это реализовать" не дошел, вот спрашиваю на русскоязычном сегменте интернета

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class HelloWorld {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
        HttpEntity httpEntity;
        HttpGet httpGet;
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            new HelloWorld().go();

        }

        private void go() throws IOException {

            CSVReader csvReader;
            String csvFile;
            //Создаем подключение
            httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

            //Формируем запрос
            httpGet = new HttpGet("http://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/spreadsheet/example.csv");

            //Отправляем запрос на сервер и получаем ответ
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            //Достаём наш файл из запроса
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            csvFile = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            //Переводит String в поток,так как CSVReader принимает на вход поток
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(IOUtils.toInputStream(csvFile));

            //Читаем наши данные из потока
            csvReader = new CSVReader(isr);

            //Выводим все строки файла или обрабатываем данные из файла как нам нужно
            String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Зависимости , я использую gradle
Файл build.gradle

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.3.6"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0"
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.5'
}
```

Ссылка на библиотеку по работе с CSV

Comment: благодарю, пример очень помог!